# actionscript display timer

Tags: actionscript-3, timer

ok so im using real basic code for a small game and ive got a timer set up on one room and cant get it to display in the endgame room please help?

this is the code i used

```
var gameStartTime:uint;
var gameTime:uint;

var gameTimeField:TextField;

gameTimeField = new TextField();
gameTimeField.x = 900;
gameTimeField.y = 50;


addChild(gameTimeField);

gameStartTime = getTimer();
gameTime = 0;

addEventListener(Event.ENTER_FRAME,showTime);

function showTime(event:Event) 
{gameTime = getTimer()-gameStartTime;
gameTimeField.text = "Time: "+clockTime(gameTime);
}
function clockTime(ms:int)
{
    var seconds:int = Math.floor(ms/100);
    var minutes:int = Math.floor(seconds/60);
    seconds -= minutes*60;

    var timeString:String = minutes+":"+String(seconds+100).substr(1,2);

    return timeString;
}
```

Comment: It's not really clear to me what your problem is. Is it that you have the time stored in the variable gameTime and you cannot access that one from somewhere else in your game?

Comment: im sorry for not being clear. ive been awake a while and havn't used actionscript before a week ago. ive set up a game where you catch balls and i have a small timer running on screen and im trying to get it to disply what it gets up to when i click on the next button to go the next sceen

Comment: So where is this code? Is it on a frame or is it in a separate file? You really have to explain a bit more on the setup of your game before anyone can give you sensible advice.

Comment: the code is on a frame with other code that brings in all the spritesand ive got 5 classes for 5 different balls and i just need the code for the third scene that brings in the data from the gameTime function

Answer (score 0):

If all your code is happening on the timeline of one MovieClip you could store the gameTime as a member of the movieclip instead of in a timeline var. This is possible since MovieClip is an 'open' class, it allows you to add members (variables, functions) to instances it.

so instead of

```
var gameTime:uint;
gameTime = getTimer()-gameStartTime;
```

you have to use 'this' to refer to the current MovieClip, so use:

```
this.gameTime = getTimer() - gameStartTime;
```

now you can reference this.gameTime on other frames in your MovieClip to read the value.

In general I would not suggest programming your game code like this - when your code starts to grow it is better to add an actual file that contains the code otherwise you'll quickly lose track of what is where, read http://www.adobe.com/devnet/flash/quickstart/external_files_as3/ for a quick introduction.